# How do I retain custom PS1 in super user mode?

Tags: bash, sudo, prompt

The problem is this:

I set a custom `PS1` in my .bashrc, but it changes to the default one when I enter super-user mode.

What I expected:

```
╓[coffee]─[Linux-Tower]─[2014-11-05, 23:41]─[~]
╙[$]-[sudo su
[sudo] password for coffee: 
╓[root]─[Linux-Tower]─[2014-11-05, 23:41]─[~]
╙[#]-[
```

What I got:

```
╓[coffee]─[Linux-Tower]─[2014-11-05, 23:41]─[~]
╙[$]-[sudo su
[sudo] password for coffee: 
root@Linux-Tower:/home#
```

So how do I set `PS1` to also be what's being used when running as root?

Comment: Put it in root's `.bashrc`...

Comment: @jasonwryan I'm not even sure where that is..

Comment: `/root/.bashrc`

Comment: @jasonwryan oh I see

Comment: I put my prompt setting in ~/.bash_prompt. I source that in my ~/.bashrc. When I change to another user, I can `. ~me/.bash_prompt`

Comment: Unless you are the only person using your server, don't mess with ~root/.bashrc

Comment: You could use 'sudo -s' instead of 'su'.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `sudo su`. The `su` is pointless as you've already become root by using `sudo`.

Use `sudo -Es` instead. This will preserve the environment. However there is a catch. Because the shell is being launched interactively, it is going to source `~/.bashrc`, which will presumably reset `$PS1`. However `$HOME` is preserved, so bash is going to use your home directory when looking for `.bashrc`, and not root's home. Thus your profile will be used.

This does have one possible issue though. As mentioned, `$HOME` is set to your user's home, thus any commands which create files in `$HOME/` will create them as root. Though this doesn't matter if the files already exist and are just overwritten.

If you truly want to preserve `$PS1`, you can do so, but it's not as clean:

```
sudo -E bash --norc
```

or

```
sudo PS1="$PS1" bash --norc
```

The main downsides to this is that this method explicitly uses `bash` as the shell, and `--norc` is a bash-specific option as well. The above `sudo -Es` method will use whatever `$SHELL` is set to, which matters if you're not using `bash`.
Also when using the `-E` method, you need to make sure `$PS1` is exported.